# Refactoring vue2 code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to refactor my code by separating authentication functionality to a different function

so in my Login function i currently have

```
  submitdata () {
    this.$axios({
      url: '/oauth/token',
      method: 'post',
      baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
      data: this.login_form
    })
      .then(
        (res) => {
          this.submitted = false
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access_token);
          localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);

          } else {
            this.$swal('Oops...', 'Invalid Login!', 'error')
          }

        },
        (err) => {
          this.submitted = false
          this.$swal('Oops...', 'Invalid Login', 'error')
        }
      )

    return
  },
```

what i would like to do is to outsource this in a different file so i have created a file  auth.js

```
auth.js
import vue from 'vue';

login(){  
  this.$axios({
    url: '/oauth/token',
    method: 'post',
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    data: this.login_form
   }).then()....
 }
```

Now i would simply like in my component to call

```
auth.login.then()...
```

But now i cannot access the Vue this.$  prototypes

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put `axios` into separate js module called let's say `api-client.js`. Then you can use it anywhere in your code simply by importing that module and you're not limited to having Vue instance which is now your problem. Another thing is having http client coupled with view entity is just not a good design in my opinion. 
So you would have something like (in pseudo-code):

api-client.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

login(){
   axios.get('url').then...
}
```

Make api-client clean and simple. Its task is [only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) to make an HTTP requests, nothing else, nothing related to view(Vue) manipulation.

login-form.vue

```
import apiClient from '/some/path/api-client'

submitdata() {
   apiClient.login().then...
}
```

Comment: what is abit confusing is when creating the apiClient shout it be a js or a vue component. Ans also i have setup my global http url and interceptors in vuejs can i also reuse them. Which is the best coding standard with alot of reusability?

Comment: `api-client` should be a js module. I think you should put your url also to api-client and then you can expose them via public methods.

Comment: I see it now, But now an example with login function if i place it in auth.js then return a promise how will i then access the vuejs http resource inside the login function in a js function. Also in my vuejs i have setup http resource base urls and interceptors as well

Comment: You don't need an acces to vue inside login function. You need to obtain the token, that's all you should care about. Then call login function from vue in response to click or something. Then in the callback you can just render proper UI for logged in user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns please read about it in general

Comment: Thanks i see the logic now